# Angular js phonecat with Firebase instead of .json files

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am new to firebase and I am trying to retrieve the data in this service from firebase instead of json files but I haven't been able to get it to work. It is based on the angularjs phonecat example

```
.factory('Article', ['$resource', FIREBASE_URL, $firebaseArray,
function ($resource, FIREBASE_URL, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "articles");
  var posts = $firebaseArray(ref);
   return $resource('views/:articleId', { }, {
  query: {method:'GET', params:{articleId: 'articles'}, isArray:true}
 });
}]);
```

And the controllers:

```
.controller('blogCtrl', ['$scope', 'Article', 
  function($scope, Article){
       $scope.articles = Article.query();
 }]);

 .controller('blogpageCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams','Article',
function($scope, $routeParams, Article){
  $scope.article = Article.get({articleId: $routeParams.articleId}, function(article){
 });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorialHere is my solution using AngularFire for https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial. I didn't use the 'service' since we have AngularFire providing functions.

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray',
  function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://your-app.firebaseio.com/phones/");
    $scope.phones = $firebaseArray(ref);
    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$firebaseObject',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $firebaseObject) {
      $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
      var ref = new Firebase("https://your-app.firebaseio.com/phones/"+$scope.phoneId);
    $scope.phone = $firebaseObject(ref);
}]);
```